# Removing carriage returns in Mysql DB

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace junk in my DB:

```
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'<p></p><p>','<p>')
```

Some tags are not getting replaced because there are line breaks between them...

In phpmyadmin I see this:

```
yadda yadda<p></p>
<p>yadda yadda
```

This didn't work..

```
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\\r\\n','');
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\\r','');
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\\r','');
```

WHERE ARE THE BREAKS COMING FROM??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 40):

```
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\r\n','');
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\n','');
```

Try the above.

Comment: It's probably advisable to run `UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\r\n','');` first, then the `\n` version as suggested above afterward.

Comment: Note my edited comment. I meant `\r\n` as a pair first, not just `\r`.

Comment: what is body in this query?

Comment: @HarishPathak body is the name of the column you want to do the replace on.

Answer (score 28):

Neither of these worked for me. Then I realized I also had paragraph breaks ¶.
This query worked for me:

```
UPDATE xxxxxx SET body = REPLACE(REPLACE(body, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
```

Comment: this is the one that did it for me.

Comment: This worked for me too... what the hell are these pilcrow symbols? I'm kind of confused on the difference between \n, \r, ¶ now. Is there a good resource out there to understand this? How did it even appear in my data?

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me!

Comment: This also worked for me whereas separating them did not. Table Info (should it prove useful to someone else): InnoDB, utf8mb4 (general_ci). MySql 5.5.5.