# MySQL: how to replace literal \r\n with special characters \r\n

Tags: mysql

I have some faulty PHP code which inserted literal \r\n characters into the database instead of the special characters representing new line and carriage return. Can anyone help me come up with a query that will replace the literals with the special characters?

Here's an SQL Fiddle setup. All I really need is something that will return the row containing "abc\r\ndef" rather than the other row. It's probably a very simple escape that's needed, but I can't work it out.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f2acb/1

Once I have that query I guess I will simply use

UPDATE test SET txt replace(txt, 'UNKNOWN EXPRESSIOn', '\r\n');

I'm running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903156/removing-carriage-returns-in-mysql-db
    UPDATE xxxxxx set txt = replace(UNKNOWN EXPRESSIOn,'\r\n','');
    UPDATE xxxxxx set txt = replace(UNKNOWN EXPRESSIOn,'\n','');

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but it did lead me to the correct answer. So this is now solved, thank you :)

Comment: could you post the answer yourself, mark it correct, so this thing goes off the radar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in a similar question that juanvan linked to.

```
UPDATE test set txt = replace(txt,'\\r\\n','\r\n');
```