# Replacing CR characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my mysql table I have a Reference field.  Users are typing in there references but they use enter.  I have a script that exports the table to csv and then import into another mysql db.  The problem is in my script that imports it into the new database it says that new line is /n (`lines terminated by '\n'`).  Now when I import it and there is an enter in the ref field it thinks it is a new line.  I've googled quite a few options and tried replacing it in the ref field but it still is vissible.

My mysql queries I've tried which did update a few rows but not everything:

```
UPDATE tablename SET `ref` = REPLACE(`ref`, '\n', '') WHERE INSTR(`ref`, '\n') > 0;
UPDATE tablename SET `ref` = REPLACE(`ref`, '\r', '') WHERE INSTR(`ref`, '\r') > 0;
```

This returns no rows, I did it just to check for the ascii codes but if I few the exported csv file in notepad++ with all characters I can see clearly the problem is [CR][LF], I've attached a printscreen of this.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE `ref`LIKE CONCAT('%',CHAR(13 ),'%')
```

[image]

What must I do in my download script to find and replace this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to the same question here: [Removing carriage returns in Mysql DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903156/removing-carriage-returns-in-mysql-db)

```
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\r\n','');
UPDATE xxxxxx set body = replace(body,'\n','');
```

Please give LiamB the credit for that answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was unable to resolve using '%\n%' or concat like you tried.
Same with using double backslashes

In the end I found using 4 backslashes returned all the records with a line feed
eg:

```
Select * from table, where ref like '%\\\\n%'
```

This was in MySQL Workbench