# Sequel Pro / Remove Line Breaks when pasting to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, replace, sequelpro

I know there have been a number of posts about this and I promise I looked through as many as I could stomach before posting my own version of it.

I'm pulling an email body from sequel and pasting it into excel as part of a greater project. Each time this value is pasted in excel though, it retains all the line breaks, skewing the greater data set.

There is a ton of ugly HTML is these specific emails that seem to be gumming up the works.

**TLDR:** What am I missing in the below select statement that would help me to remove these extraneous line breaks and other formatting when pasting multiple rows like this from sequel to excel.

I'm banging my head over this as none of the `replace()` functions seem to do the trick - can anyone help?

`SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(re.body, '\r', ' '),'\n',' ')
FROM received_emails re
WHERE re.from LIKE '%@domain%';`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   <head>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>     <style type="text/css"> body {     margin:0;     color:#333; }  a {     text-decoration:none;     color:#006699; }  p {     margin:0px; }  img {     border:0;     margin:0; }  /* container */ #container {     width:540px;     margin:0 auto; }  #content {     width:500px;     margin:0 20px; }  /* header */ #header {     border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;     padding-top:10px;     padding-left:0px;     padding-right:0px;     padding-bottom:10px; }  #title p{     font-size:20px;     font-family: "arial", "sans-serif"; }  #amazonLogo{     width:107px;     height:31px; }  /* verification msg */ #verificationMsg {     padding-left:0;     padding-top:9px;     padding-bottom:9px; }  #verificationMsg p {     font-size:14px;     font-family: "arial", "sans-serif"; }  #verificationMsg .otp {     font-size:18px;     font-weight:bold;     padding-top:18px; }  /* account security */ #accountSecurity {     padding-left:0;     padding-top:9px;     padding-bottom:9px; }  #accountSecurity p {     font-size:14px;     font-family: "arial", "sans-serif"; }  /* closing */ #closing {     padding-left:0;     padding-top:9px;     padding-bottom:9px; }  #closing p {     font-size:14px;     font-family: "arial", "sans-serif"; }      </style>     <title></title>   </head>   <body><img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.domain.url/gp/r.html?C=PEZFBQGDUNSN&M=urn:rtn:msg:20180529165336df0ef80e18cf4d10b613aec2fe80p0na&R=2ZJED16MJLBB2&T=O&U=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&H=LOVUJXIQPO7KEAPOH3USA0AXVRKA&ref_=pe_1568390_127719720_opens" />   <table align="center" cellspacing="0" id="container" cellpadding="0">     <tbody>     <tr>       <td>         <table cellspacing="0" id="content" cellpadding="0">           <tbody>           <tr>             <td id="header">               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">                 <tbody>                 <tr>                   <td width="250" id="logo"> <img src="https://images-na.com/images/G/01/x-locale/cs/te/logo._CB152417367_.png" id="logo"/>                  </td>                   <td width="250" id="title" valign="top" align="right"><p></p></td>                 </tr>                 </tbody>               </table>             </td>           </tr>            <tr>             <td id="verificationMsg">               <p>Hello,<br/> some text</p>               <p class="otp">197205</p>             </td>           </tr>            <tr>             <td id="accountSecurity">               <p>some more text  <br/><br/>so much text  <br/><br/>text text text text text   </p>             </td>           </tr>            <tr>             <td id="closing">               <p>text!!!         </p>             </td>           </tr>           </tbody>         </table>       </td>     </tr>     </tbody>   </table>   <img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.domain.url/gp/r.html?M=urn:rtn:msg:20180529165336df0ef80e18cf4d10b613aec2fe80p0na&R=2ZJED16MJLBB2&T=E&U=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&H=RQY711YLA1V0F5MUULVC8VU7ZPKA&ref_=pe_1568390_127719720_open" /></body>   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, was able to drill down into some additional issues with needing to include the REPLACE() function in other areas, as well as pasting as values only.

This post was helpful as well: [Removing carriage returns in Mysql DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903156/removing-carriage-returns-in-mysql-db)